# Deriving the optical Bloch equations as given in Wikipedia from the von Neumann equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, operators, density-operator

Different from my previous [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291688/), which dealt with a convention my professor used, I now want to derive the optical Bloch equations in a semiclassical model, but this time in the shape they are given in for example on [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Bloch_equations#cite_note-metcalf-2)
\begin{align}
  \frac{\mathrm d    \rho_{gg}}{\mathrm dt}
&=\frac i2(\Omega^*  \bar\rho_{eg}-\Omega\ \ \bar\rho_{ge})\\
  \frac{\mathrm d    \rho_{ee}}{\mathrm dt}
&=\frac i2(\Omega\ \ \bar\rho_{ge}-\Omega^*  \bar\rho_{eg})\\
  \frac{\mathrm d\bar\rho_{ge}}{\mathrm dt}
&=\frac i2\Omega^*  (\rho_{ee}-\rho_{gg})-i\delta\bar\rho_{ge}\\
  \frac{\mathrm d\bar\rho_{eg}}{\mathrm dt}
&=\frac i2\Omega\ \ (\rho_{gg}-\rho_{ee})+i\delta\bar\rho_{eg}
\end{align}
I'm not interested in the attenuation terms, so I omitted them.
Problems arise with the off-diagonal equations: Instead of $\delta$, the factor in front of $\rho_{ge}$ becomes $\omega_0$. Does anybody know where a semiclassical model and the von Neumann equations are used to derive the optical Bloch equations? I have only found this derivation for pure states, but in my opinion this derivation lacks some generality.

Comment: Your original question post has a lot of minor looking typoes that threaten to completely derail the correctness of the set of equations, so I think I do need to ask if you understood what the bar above $\bar\rho$ is meant to mean, etc. You also had mistakes in the eg ge parts, sign errors, conjugation errors etc. I do not know what is happening here; came in just to reverse a rather dangerous edit on your question, and found the need to merge the sane parts of the edit with your question.