# Why does the coherence decay with factor 1/2 in Optical Bloch equations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

Why is there a factor of 1/2 in the damping rate of the coherences ($\rho_{12}$)? In the equation below the damping is provided by the coefficient $\gamma$.
I understand the damping of the ground state and excited state, but I have no clue of the origin of the factor 1/2 in the coherence damping.

The [optical Bloch equations that I use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Bloch_equations) are given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dt} \rho_{11} &= \frac{i}{2}\Omega_0 (\rho_{21}^* - \rho^*_{12}) + \gamma \rho_{22} \\
\frac{d}{dt} \rho_{22} &= \frac{i}{2}\Omega_0 (\rho^*_{12} - \rho^*_{21}) 
- \gamma \rho_{22} \\
\frac{d}{dt} \rho^*_{12} &= \frac{i}{2}\Omega_0 (\rho_{22} - \rho_{11}) -\left(\frac{\gamma}{2} +i \delta\right) \rho^*_{12} \\
\frac{d}{dt} \rho^*_{21} &= \frac{i}{2}\Omega_0 (\rho_{11} - \rho_{22}) -\left(\frac{\gamma}{2} -i \delta\right)  \rho^*_{21}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: Please provide more context. Where do these equations come from and what do they represent?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292836/2451

Comment: This 1/2 is coming from the derivation of Lindblad master equation.